# Deploy logic app using bicep - Convert JSON to valid Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I want to generate a bicepfor building a Logic App. The boilerplate for this would be

```
resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: 'lapp-${options.suffix}'
  location: options.location
  properties: {
    definition: {
      // here comes the definition
    }
  }
}
```

My comment shows the point where the definition of the app itself would be placed. If I know take a JSON from an existing logic app (I spared some stuff for brevity):

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {},
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {

                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

you would have to tranform this to something like this:

```
{
    definition: {
        '$schema': "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#"
        actions: {}
        contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
        outputs: {}
        parameters: {}
        triggers: {
            'manual': {
                inputs: {

                }
                kind: 'Http'
                type: 'Request'
            }
        }
    }
    parameters: {}
}
```

That means for instance:

- remove trailing commas
- remove quotes on properties
- single quote some properties like the `schema` or custom action names
- escape single quotes when they appear in values which is common in Logic apps

Is there any converter which can transform a JSON structure into a valid bicep? I do not mean `bicep decompile` because this assumes that you've got an already valid ARM template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach is to keep your definition in a separate file and pass the json as a parameter.

main.bicep:

```bicep
// Parameters
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param logicAppName string
param logicAppDefinition object

// Basic logic app
resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  properties: {
    state: 'Enabled'
    definition: logicAppDefinition.definition
    parameters: logicAppDefinition.parameters
  }
}
```

Then you can deploy your template like that (using az cli and powershell here):

```powersshell
$definitionPath="full/path/of/the/logic/app/definition.json"
az deployment group create `
  --resource-group "resource group name" `
  --template-file "full/path/of/the/main.bicep" `
  --parameters logicAppName="logic app name" `
  --parameters logicAppDefinition=@$definitionPath
```

With this approach you dont have to modify your "infra-as-code" every time you update the logic app.

Comment: And again the answer was too obvious for me :-). Although I have to admit that the problem of transforming JSON into Bicep still bothers me.

Comment: Whatever json object you're passing to your bicep template will be interpreted as a "bicep yaml object". It s just the synthax that is different. depends on the problem you're trying to solve, it could be handy tho

Answer (score 5):

Adding an another approach. Load the workflow file inside the bicep file using *loadTextContent(file.json)* and parse it as JSON using *json()* method and access the definition and parameters straight inside the bicep file, avoiding passing the workflow file as parameter to the CLI

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param logicAppName string
var logicAppDefinition = json(loadTextContent('LogicApp.workflow.json'))


// Basic logic app
resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  properties: {
    state: 'Enabled'
    definition: logicAppDefinition.definition
    parameters: logicAppDefinition.parameters
  }
}
```

Comment: loadTextContent(file.json) has size limitation so it won't be practical for most of the logic apps.

Comment: `loadJsonContent(file.json)` has instead of ~130.000 characters a ~1 Million character size limitation. But still a size limitation.